# Date object passed as prop becomes [object Object] instead of [object Date]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A component in my project is calling a function from another file and passing it an object with three properties: `stringProp`, `numProp`, and `dateProp` (which is a `Date` object the current component receives as a prop from an input component)

```
const result = MyAPI.calc({stringProp: {stringProp}, numProp: {numProp}, dateProp: {dateProp}})

console.log(`{stringProp: ${stringProp}, numProp: ${numProp}, dateProp: ${dateProp} ${Object.prototype.toString.call(dateProp)}}`)
// >>> {stringProp: something, numProp: 123, dateProp: Fri Jan 19 2024 [object Date]}
```

When the `calc` function is called:

```
export const calc = (props) =>
{
    const stringProp = props.stringProp || ''
    const numProp = props.numProp || 0

    console.log(`props.dateProp: ${props.dateProp} ${Object.prototype.toString.call(dateProp)}`)
    // >>> props.dateProp: [object Object] [object Object]
    ...
}
```

`numProp` and `stringProp` are coming through as expected, but `dateProp` is not. These three props were already passed as parameters from one component to another, and came through as expected.

In the original input component, `dateProp` is saved to state with the `useState` hook.

I've seen a few similar questions, but not many have been answered, or the solution was to fix a typo which I don't think is the case now.

Update: per @KyleRifqi's answer below, calling `JSON.stringify(props.dateProp, null, '\t')` will return a value like `"2024-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"` which shows `typeof string`. How would I convert this into a date? `new Date()` does not work and returns `Invalid Date`. There are a lot of older answers using `match` and/or a reviver function to convert it, but is there a more modern robust approach?

Answer (score 2):

When an object is converted to a string, it is converted as "[object Object]". If you want to console log an object use the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function.

Example:

```
console.log(`props.dateProp: ${JSON.stringify(props.dateProp, null, '\t')}`)
```

Comment: That works and returns a date string like "2024-01-19T00:00:00.000Z". How could I reliably convert this back into a `Date` object that I can work with? I updated the question above with additional detail

Comment: You don't need to convert it back, it already is a Date object. its just that you cant console log it without first converting it into a string properly.

Comment: I thought so as well, but if I use any `Date` methods on it, JS throws an error. If I check `typeof` it returns `string`

Comment: are you converting it to a string before checking it? try type checking `props.dateProp` itself and see what it returns.

Comment: Looking at your update it seems you misunderstood what `JSON.stringify()` does, its only meant to convert the date into a string. the original `props.dateProps` is still a date and will return a type of `object`